# EXTRA_START_PLAYER cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android, ide

```
package com.example.tictactoemain;

import com.example.tictactoelib.GameActivity;
import com.example.tictactoelib.GameView.State;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import com.example.tictactoelib.GameActivity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void startGame(boolean startWithHuman) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(GameActivity.EXTRA_START_PLAYER, startWithHuman ? State.PLAYER1.getValue() : State.PLAYER2.getValue());
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

GameActivity :

```
package com.example.tictactoelib;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.example.tictactoelib.GameView.State;

public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String EXTRA_START_PLAYER = 
            "com.example.android.tictactoelib.GameActivity.EXTRA_START_PLAYER";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Inside of MainActivity I am getting an error:

```
EXTRA_START_PLAYER cannot be resolved or is not a field.
```

The main project references tictactoelib as a library with a green check box. As well tictactoelib was created as a library project. Although EXTRA_START_PLAYER is defined as a public static final String the main project does not seem to see it. I am piecing together the TicTacToe SDK android-17 project so I am trying to resolve the error though I do not yet understand where the problem is.

I am also wondering the exact meaning of: `="com.example.android.tictactoelib.GameActivity.EXTRA_START_PLAYER";`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: try removing the final modifier

Comment: I tried removing final but the error persists.

Comment: press save all and it should work

Comment: I did a save all but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
private void startGame(boolean startWithHuman) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GameActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("com.example.android.tictactoelib.GameActivity.EXTRA_START_PLAYER", startWithHuman ? State.PLAYER1.getValue() : State.PLAYER2.getValue());
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

instead if you are using it in just one activity